# Divide the video to bytes

Tags: java, video, byte, video-encoding, bytebuffer

i want to convert the video to bytes it gives me result but i think the result is not correct because i test it for different videos and the gives me the same result so 
can any one help please to do how to convert video to byte

```
String filename = "D:/try.avi";
byte[] myByteArray = filename.getBytes();
for(int i = 0; i<myByteArray.length;i ++)
{
    System.out.println(myByteArray[i]);
}
```

Any help Please?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Convert video content to bytes or filename to bytes?

Comment: What is the point of doing a byte-by-byte comparison of video files?  I could understand frame-by-frame, but byte-by-byte does not make much sense.

Comment: i want to convert the content of video to bytes

Answer (score 4):

```
String filename = "D:/try.avi";
byte[] myByteArray = filename.getBytes();
```

That is converting the file **name** to bytes, not the file **content.**

As for reading the content of the file, see the [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) lesson of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: then do you know how to convert the content of the file?

Comment: Again, a little louder this time.  **Why?**  What feature are you intending to provide the user?

Comment: i just want to find the quality of service for transferring the video over mesh network then graph the result so i want to convert the video to data as byte to do the statistic

Comment: *"mesh network"*  Huh, new term for me.  So the real problem comes down to verifying the copy 'sent via the network' to the original file?

Comment: the only problem is to getting the content of the video as bytes

Answer (score 2):

Videos in same container formats start with same bytes. The codec used determines the actual video files.

I suggest you read more about container file formats and codecs first if you plan developing video applications.

But you have a different problem. As Andrew Thompson correctly pointed out, you are getting the bytes of the *filename string*.

The correct approach would be:

```
private static File fl=new File("D:\video.avi");
byte[] myByteArray = getBytesFromFile(fl);
```

Please also bear in mind that terminals usually have fixed buffer size (on Windows, it's several lines), so outputting a big chunk of data will display only last several lines of it.

**Edit:** Here's an implementation of getBytesFromFile; a java expert may offer more standard approach.

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = openFile(file.getPath());

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();

        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
            Assert.assertExp(false);
            logger.warn(file.getPath()+" is too big");
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        // debug - init array
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            bytes[i] = 0x0;
        }

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }

        // Close the input stream and return bytes
        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);`  Huh..  Never heard of the IO package or that method.  Can you link to the JavaDocs?

Comment: Was that java? Sorry, I didn't see the tag :))) That's what we get when we have two so similar languages.

Comment: *"Was that java?"*  It is the same as it started.  'Java', not 'java'.

Comment: I updated the answer with java example, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: And while I do agree that spelling JAVA or javA is wrong, and while I try to support all language advocates to spell their languages as they wish (I do not like either when anyone spells Lisp as LISP), I think Java is also java, and Lisp is also lisp. Though C is not c.

Comment: There's no accounting for what people think.

Comment: I agree. And there's no accounting for taste.

Comment: getBytesFromFile(fl) it gives me error it is not a general function so i should create this function??

Comment: Here's also a better, stream-oriented approach: http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/get-byte-array.shtml

Comment: are you sure it is worked with you because it gives me an error also

Comment: What error does it give to you? Did you try reading the file as a stream?

Comment: try this: `getBytesFromFile(java.io.File file)`

Comment: or try `import java.io.*` at the top of the file.

Comment: can you specify what kind of error do are you getting? there can be million reasons.

Comment: @AndrewThompson provided a great resource in his answer; here's what you need and it's easier: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

Answer (score -2):

If you want to read the contents of the video file then use `File`.

```
String filename = "D:/try.avi";
File file=new File(filename);
byte myByteArray[]=new byte[(int)file.length()];
RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile(file,"rw");
raf.read(myByteArray);
```